# numberformat exception with edittext in android isnot working

Tags: android, numberformatexception

here i created one edittext and send button and if user enter any digit in this textbox i dont want to redirect him to next page for that i used numberformat exception ..its working fine when we enters only number but when we enter character+number its going to next page.so what should i do..?

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText edittext   =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message=edittext.getText().toString();
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(message);

    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.print("Errr"+nfe.getMessage());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Searchable_inputType) for your [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html):

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />
```

Comment: yeah.but i got error of No resource identifier found for attribute 'inputype' in package 'android

Comment: What is your min and max SDK?

Comment: minimum sdk is 8 and maximum is 18

Comment: Try changing your min to 11 and see if the problem persists?